# can't figure out missing libraries or imports

Tags: java, android

So, after reinstalling the SDK and some tools in Android Studio, I keep getting this errors like these:

```
Error:(5, 19) java: package android.app does not exist
Error:(6, 18) java: package android.os does not exist
Error:(7, 20) java: package android.view does not exist
Error:(8, 22) java: package android.widget does not exist
Error:(11, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Activity
...
```

part of the code where the errors lead:

[image: picture of code]

I suspect that something has gone missing while messing with the SDK as that part of the code was fine beforehand. project code is not mine, i am still a complete rookie in Java. My apologies if there is a really trivial solution for this, but I've spent hours on googling and trying but can't get it to work.

any ideas what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart` > `Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: one of the first things I tried. unfortunately doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the location of Android SDK inside Android Studio? You can go to Preferences -> System Settings -> Android SDK and check whether the field "Android SDK Location" is set to the correct path

Comment: location is: C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
seems right to me

Comment: What about File -> Project Structure ? Check SDK Manager if the path is the same everywhere.

Comment: android sdk homepath is the same as above. classpath goes to: \Sdk\platforms\android-26\data\res sourcepath: \Sdk\sources\android-26 again it all looks good to me.